# Is there any way to hide mobile carrier from applications?

Tags: applications, sim-card, mobile-network, android-12

I have 2 applications that refuse to work (fully or at all) if I insert a SIM card in a smartphone.

Disabling mobile data and geolocation (which is not allowed by default anyway) doesn't change anything. And what surprised me the most — these apps don't check your location or anything (VPN + location mocking also don't do anything), they just check your SIM card and that's all. In other words, I have to pop out SD+SIM tray every time for them to work as expected. (Well, actually, I think some IPs are not available from my country, therefore I have to use VPN sometimes too, but for the most part they work without it.)

I was wondering if there is any way to prevent them from looking up SIM card carrier or just mocking it with another name (like geolocation).

Note: my phone is not rooted and its Android version is 12.

Comment: Select one one of these apps -> clear data of that app -> revoke or make sure to NOT grant "Phone" permission and "Device ID & call Information" -> check if the app is still able to detect SIM card presence.

Comment: @Firelord, the thing is only one has a "Phone" permission and that's it. The other one has only "Location" which was always disabled. Which backs up my surprise about how my SIM card info is transparent to all apps. Maybe I'll search for an Android API regarding SIM card.